# How to execute script on logging out?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm reading [The Unix Programming Environment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013937681X).
There is an exercise question to print how much CPU time you have consumed when you log off by editing `.profile`.

I tried with this

```
trap 'times' 0 1 2 15
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

In bash, the `~/.bash_logout` file will be executed upon exiting a login shell. Put your code in that file.

Answer (score 2):

From the tag, I'm guessing that this is in bash.  Bash defaults to `.bash_profile` and only uses `.profile` if the former does not exists.  Try putting the trap line in .bash_profile.

Alternatively, you could put the following in `.bash_logout`:

```
times
read -t 5 # timeout after 5 seconds
```